# Executing DMV catalog query after a SSAS cube process forces execution of all DB scripts

Tags: process, ssas, dmv, cube-script

After processing an 2012 SSAS cube, then executing a DMV query, such as:

```
select * from $system.mdschema_sets where [cube_name]='cube name'
```

i see in sql profiler it executes scripts of ALL cubes in the database, disregarding the restriction in the query. As my customer's database has many cubes, this operation takes more than 20 secs.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can you monitor this in Profiler connected to SSAS? Turn on all Execute MDX Script XXXX events and let us know which ones have long durations. Then copy the slow statements into your question. Maybe some named sets can be optimized.

Comment: Do you have any dynamic named sets (as in CREATE DYNAMIC NAMED SET)? If so you can try this trick: http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2014/02/18/when-dynamic-sets-are-not-dynamic.aspx